# Why am I getting "Connection Closed on Error" with XMPP

Tags: xmpp, smack

XMPP Library being used:

```
 "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-java7" % "4.1.8",
 "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-tcp" % "4.1.8",
 "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-core" % "4.1.8",
 "org.igniterealtime.smack" % "smack-extensions" % "4.1.8",
```

Hi,

We have a XMPP server which connects to FCM XMPP server, sometime we see following errors from our XMPP Connection sometimes:

```
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] Nov 30, 2018 7:08:38 PM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1177)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:956)
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:971)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 PROCESSORS [ERROR] XMPPConnectionListener -> connectionClosedOnError: null input contained no data
java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093) ~[stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1177) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:956) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:971) [stormjar.jar:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [INFO] 07:08:38 PM XMPPConnection closed due to an exception (1)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] java.io.EOFException: input contained no data
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.fillBuf(MXParser.java:3003)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.more(MXParser.java:3046)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.parseProlog(MXParser.java:1410)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.nextImpl(MXParser.java:1395)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.xmlpull.mxp1.MXParser.next(MXParser.java:1093)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1177)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:956)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:971)
2018-11-30T19:08:38.306+05:30 STDIO [ERROR] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am not able to not able to find what is the reason for these, why these are coming because same code works most of the time, but some times suddenly I start to get this error. I also see same reported [here](https://igniterealtime.jiveon.com/thread/16941) long back but no resolution.

Comment: check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761115/5853262)

Comment: @MahdiMoqadasi Thanks for your comment, however I am running it on Linux, and mostly this works, only sometimes I get this error.

Comment: then check out [this answer too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48866757/5853262):)